# How to Append Button Values to a Link URL with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a little questionnaire. I'd like to be able to collect answers (button clicks) and later pass them via link.

So far I have this code. Problem is that when a button from another row is clicked, it replaced the other one in a link URL.

How could i do it, so these values get appended to the link like this:

example.com?z=0&q1=a&q2=b...

Hope someone can help.

```js
var actionUrl = 'http://example.com?z=0';
 
function b1(element){document.getElementById("action-link").href = actionUrl + '&q1=' + element.value;}
function b2(element){document.getElementById("action-link").href = actionUrl + '&q2=' + element.value;}

document.getElementById('action-link').href = actionUrl;
```

```html
    <button name="quiz1" value="a" onClick="b1(this);">CLICK ME</button>
    <button name="quiz1" value="b" onClick="b1(this);">CLICK ME</button></td>
<br>
<br>

    <button name="quiz2" value="a" onClick="b2(this);">CLICK ME</button>
    <button name="quiz2" value="b" onClick="b2(this);">CLICK ME</button></td>


<a id='action-link' href=''>Click to continue</a>
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for a form, with radio buttons (not JavaScript) and a submit button (not a link).

Answer (score 0):

You can append to the current `href` of `action-link` like so:

`document.getElementById("action-link").href += '&q1=' + element.value;`

See changes below:

```js
function b1(element) {
  document.getElementById("action-link").href += '&q1=' + element.value;
}

function b2(element) {
  document.getElementById("action-link").href += '&q2=' + element.value;
}
```

```html
<button name="quiz1" value="a" onClick="b1(this);">CLICK ME</button>
<button name="quiz1" value="b" onClick="b1(this);">CLICK ME</button></td>
<br>
<br>

<button name="quiz2" value="a" onClick="b2(this);">CLICK ME</button>
<button name="quiz2" value="b" onClick="b2(this);">CLICK ME</button></td>


<a id='action-link' href='http://example.com?z=0'>Click to continue</a>
```

Comment: What happens if I select option a for quiz 1 and change my mind to select option b instead ? With your solution, the parameter q1 will appear twice. The url will be `http://example.com/?z=0&q1=a&q1=b`

Comment: Yes, that's what i was afraid of. It keeps stacking the parameters instead of keeping q1 and q2 static.